# C++ long double precision difference with and without using namespace std;

Tags: c++, std

I have stumbled upon quirky C++ behavior that I cannot explain.

I am trying to calculate the dimensions of an image when resizing it (maintaining its ratio) to fit as much screen as possible. The x, y variables are dimensions of the image and X, Y variables are dimensions of the screen. When the resulting dimensions are not integers, I need to round them using standard rules of mathematics.

This program for inputs `499999999999999999 10 1000000000000000000 19` gives the (incorrect) answer of `950000000000000000 19`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    long long x, y, X, Y;
    std::cin >> x >> y >> X >> Y;

    long double ratio = std::min((long double)X/x, (long double)Y/y);

    x = round(ratio*x);
    y = round(ratio*y);

    std::cout << x << " " << y << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

However, code below (only change is `using namespace std;` and removing `std::` from `main` function body) gives the correct answer of `949999999999999998 19`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long long x, y, X, Y;
    cin >> x >> y >> X >> Y;

    long double ratio = min((long double)X/x, (long double)Y/y);

    x = round(ratio*x);
    y = round(ratio*y);

    cout << x << " " << y << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I am using `g++ (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0` and compiling the program with `g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow`.

Comment: To add more to this: It also doesn't work when I change the std::min(...) to a simple if (x < y) check.

Comment: There are multiple `round` functions (from c and from c++). You should maybe take a look at the differences between them. Specifically the parameters they take.

Comment: that's one of the reasons why ["using namespace std" shouldn't be used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/995714)

Comment: @phuclv In this case the version with `using namespace std;` happens to have the desired behavior. I think the correct lesson here is, additionally, to always qualify standard library functions with `std::` even if their names may be imported into the global namespace (for declarations from C headers).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the first case you are calling [`double round(double)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/round) function from the global namespace, which is pulled in by the `cmath` header.

In the second case you are calling overloaded [`long double std::round(long double)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round) function from the `std` namespace since your are `using namespace std`.

You can fix your code by adding `std::` in front of `round`, as in:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    long long x, y, X, Y;
    std::cin >> x >> y >> X >> Y;

    auto ratio = std::min((long double)X / x, (long double)Y / y);

    x = std::round(ratio * x); // <-- add std:: here
    y = std::round(ratio * y); // <-- add std:: here

    std::cout << x << " " << y;
    return 0;
}
```

UPDATE:

To explain what's going on here, when you call `round` in the first case, `ratio * x` is implicitly converted to `double` (which can only store 15 significant digits) before it is passed to the function.

This leads to loss of precision and an unexpected result in your case. No quirks.

Comment: Well that makes sense, thank you. But why is [double round(double)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/round) called, when it is defined in `math.h` (which I do not include)? It is the 'default' round function to call in C++?

Comment: @k-dx `<cmath>` may, or may not, include `math.h` to use things from it. Depends on which compiler you use. A C++ header is allowed to include any other header it needs, exactly which ones varies between implementations.